# Xcode 8.2 Interface Builder Update Frame & Constraint Issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated from Xcode 7.3 to 8.2. I was using autolayouts and size classes in Interface Builder in 7.3 and everything worked fine. Now in 8.2 the IB preview doesn't correctly represent the positions of the views. However when I run it on a device or a simulator it looks fine. But if I update frames or update constraints in the preview everything gets jumbled up.

Is there anything I can do to stop update frames or update constraints mucking everything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what the problem was. There was nothing wrong with the constraints I had. The issue was that in Xcode 7 the storyboard was in ipad size. Initially when I loaded the project in Xcode 8, it opened to view as iphone 7 plus size. When I changed the storyboard to view as ipad pro size and updated frames it fixed everything. And then when I changed to view as iphone 7 plus size it resized everything perfectly as it should have done in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Near the Stack button, there is a new "Update frame" button, its just left to the stack button

Comment: Clicking "Update Frame" messes the storyboard up.

Comment: that's because you have wrong constraints. Check them up again maybe you forgot something